# Rewrite rule for htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Hi how can I change my url http://localhost/worldofcontrol/search/ic3500a192c to http://localhost/worldofcontrol/ic3500a192c. how to change in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ search/product_details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ search/product_details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: my code is something like this RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ search/product_details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/search/"
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ product_details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: Please add all of this information to your question with proper code formatting. Also, read [MCVE]. Thanks

Comment: ewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ search/product_details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: @philantrovert thank you please check now